# Programmatically distinguish between High Anonymous Proxy, Anonymous Proxy, Transparent Proxy

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, transparentproxy

Suppose I have a proxy IP address, but no infos about it.

Is this possible to know from scratch which kind of proxy it is (distant webservers doesn't know I'm behind a proxy, distant webservers know I'm behind a proxy but doesn't know my IP, distant webservers know both infos)?

Is there a simple test to verify which infos are known about me when I'm navigating?

[edit]

If someone has a simple answer like "no because [etc]", he's welcomed. My first question is "is it feasable".

Comment: Does a "service" like [Lagado Proxy Test](http://www.lagado.com/proxy-test) work?  I tried to load a different one, but it was blocked by my work proxy.

Comment: If Lagado Proxy Test accepts to receive 100000 requests, it would be perfect. But I guess it's against their T&C. It's for a proxy switcher method I'll add in a C# program (WebProxy of a WebRequest). Thanks  for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lagado Proxy Text](http://www.lagado.com/proxy-test) mentioned by Joshua Drake in comments works, so it is feasible. The important thing is now to learn how does it work.

Its operation is pretty simple: just be a website. So if you can afford to set up a website which will do exactly the same and will cope with all the traffic you're going to send to it, the problem is solved.

What should such a website do? Check for headers sent by client. The relevant ones are mentioned on the Lagado's page: Via, Forwarded, X-Forwarded-For and Client-ip.

The rest should be easy.

And answering your second question: see [BrowserSpy](http://browserspy.dk/).

Comment: I just checked BrowserSpy. It's very friendly. I guess your answer is gonna be the best, since for the rest, I'll need to read some websites T&Cs.